# Show $x$ belongs to the span of the columns of $A$ if $(AA^T + I)x = Ab$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ without assumptions about its rank.

If $(AA^T + I)x = Ab$, show that $x$ belongs to the span of the columns of $A$.

I know that I must essentially find some vector $v$ such that $x = Av$ but I'm having difficulty doing so. I thought to perhaps use the geometric matrix series, but I don't think the assumptions for convergence necessarily hold.

Comment: [+1] Somebody has downvoted this well written question, I don't understand why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Distribute $x$ into the parenthesis, and move the term $AA^T$ to RHS. and then factor out $A$. Call $v = b- A^T x ~$. This $v$ works!